# Create Devise user in two databases with same records simultaneously

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using rails 4 and want to integrate some external api, for which I have a situation where I have to **create user in two databases with same records simultaneously**.

I am using ***Devise*** for this rails application, so far I have done following to save user record in another database:

`config/database.yml`

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: test_openmeetings_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

openmeetings_dev:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: openmeetings
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

`models/User.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :new_password, :firstname, :lastname, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :confirmation_token
  attr_accessor :new_password

  # creating user record to another database just after Devise user is created
  after_create :save_to_openmeetings


  def save_to_openmeetings    
    user = last_user

    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("openmeetings_dev").connection
    sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, login) VALUES ('#{user.firstname}', '#{user.lastname}', '#{user.email}')"
    connection.execute(sql)

    # reconnect database to original state
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("#{Rails.env}").connection
  end  

  def last_user
    User.last
  end
end
```

**PROBLEM**
1. Although it is properly creating Users in both databases (from console log), the problem I am facing is, Data exists in another database(openmeetings) but that data doesn't exists In my original database (test_openmeetings_development)

1. Connection is not resetting back to original database (test_openmeetings_development)

May be whatever I am doing is not a good idea, So, Please share me logics that can solve my problem. Or please let me know what I am missing in this code (why it is not working?)

Thanks

Comment: This seems like completely the wrong approach to me. You should consider either 1. master-slave replication or 2. periodic snapshots moved from one to the other. What is your reason for needing two databases?

Comment: Thanks Dark Falcon for you suggestion. Any more suggestions??

Comment: @przbadu how did you solve this problem? I need to accomplish similar scenario

Comment: @MicFin: I will update it, Please give me some time (may be today/tomorrow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All other configuration are same and changes are below:

1) create user in openmeeting database in `after_create` callbacks

`models/user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :new_password, :firstname, :lastname, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :confirmation_token
  attr_accessor :new_password

  # creating user record to another database just after Devise user is created
  after_create :save_to_openmeetings

  def save_to_openmeetings
    OpenMeeting.create_user(self)
  end
end
```

2) Create `models/open_meeting.rb`

````
class OpenMeeting < ActiveRecord::Base

  # override establish_connection method
  def self.establish_connection
    super(:openmeetings_dev)
  end

  # create connection to your new database for me ```:openmeetings_dev```
  establish_connection


  def self.create_user(user)
    firstname = "#{ActiveRecord::Base::sanitize(user.firstname)}" # escape sql injection
    lastname = "#{ActiveRecord::Base::sanitize(user.lastname)}" # escape sql injection
    login = "#{ActiveRecord::Base::sanitize(user.email)}" # escape sql injection
    password = "#{ActiveRecord::Base::sanitize(user.new_password)}" # escape sql injection

    sql = ("INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, login, password) VALUES ('#{firstname}', '#{lastname}', '#{login}', '#{password}')")
    connection.execute(sql)   # execute create sql statement
  end

end
````

This solution is working for me, but I think, there may be better solution than this, So, please post if there is any new solution to this problem

Thanks